# calling function of one controller from another

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm new to angular and I need to call function in another controller in angular js.How it is possible? please help me thanks in advance

1. Html File

> ```
> <a> <i ng-click="open('sm')"></i>
>   <span>test</span>
> </a>
> <div ng-controller="MapModuleController">
> <scrip enter code here`t type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
>     <div class="modal-body">
>         {{ items }} // not display anything
>     </div>
>     <div class="modal-footer">
>         <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="ok()">{{ 'generic_ok' | translate}}</button>
>     </div>
> </script>
> </div>
> ```

2.Controller

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance,items) {

                $scope.items = items;
                $scope.ok = function () {
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };

                $scope.cancel = function () {
                    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                };
            });

        app.controller('MapModuleController', ['$scope','$uibModal',
                '$rootScope',function ($scope, $uibModal, $rootScope, ) {

    $scope.testFunction = function(){
    // want to call this function on press of okay button
    };

     $scope.msg = 'done';

                $scope.open = function () {

                    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
                        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
                        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',

                        resolve: {
                            items: function () {
                                return $scope.msg;
                            }
                        }

                    });
    });
```

I am new to SO Please bar me with formatting.

Comment: In angular their is a way to bind function between directive and a controller but I am not sure of controller and controller....but why do you need to call a controller function from another controller ...what is the main purpose behind it???

Answer (score 0):

You can inject one controller to another as below:

```
'use strict';

reachApp.controller('dashboardController', ['$scope','$controller', function ($scope, $controller) {
                var feedbackModel = $scope.$new(); 
                 $controller('feedbackController',{$scope : feedbackModel });
                 feedbackModel.getLatestMeetingRating(); //And call the method on the newScope.
        });
```